vue js using onclick event
currently I'm working on vue js 3, using simple-datatables
<script setup lang="ts">
//imports

const handleClickDetails = (id: string) => {  
  console.log("here: ", id);
};
<script>

and on my html, I have:
    <VSimpleDatatables 
      :options="dataTableOptions"
      :data="filteredData"
      :key="filteredData.length" 
    >
      <template v-slot:default>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" :data-sortable="false"> Action </th>
            <th scope="col" >ID-Oper.</th>
            <th scope="col" >Name</th> 
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(item , index) in filteredData" :key="index">
            <td scope="col" class="td-action">
              <div 
                class="td-action-div"
              >
                <i class="iconify larger-icon" data-icon="feather:info" aria-hidden="true"  onclick="handleClickDetails(item.id)"></i>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td scope="col" >{{ item.name || "-" }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </template>
    </VSimpleDatatables>

so, I have a issue, If  I clicked on "action" on icon "details" o got this:
Uncaught ReferenceError: handleClickDetails is not defined
what's wrong???
maybe using datatable on vue js I can't use onclick?

The onclick tag can be used just fine, it's just it is a native attribute and your function defined in the setup script is not available in the global scope. As such you have to bind it's value with an appropriate tag on the component level.
Instead of using onlick you should use v-on:click or @click for short.
<i
 class="iconify larger-icon"
 data-icon="feather:info"
 aria-hidden="true"
 @click="handleClickDetails(item.id)"
>
</i>

Please refer to Event Handling documentation

I tried with v-on:click and @click and not work, this is so weird

@alex "not work" in which way? Is there an error? The answer is the way click event is supposed to be handled. simple-datatables isn't Vue library, it's unknown what is VSimpleDatatables, how it works and what the possible implications could be

console don't show any error, I'm thinking that simple-datatables could be block the event click, what do you think?

try @click.stop= or @click.prevent=

I tried, but don't worked

can you try to replace this  icon with  and check if it works? <button @click="handleClickDetails(item.id)" >i</button>
